# How to avoid validation of few text box in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can ignore some text box ignore for validation checking. Below code is applied for all text but I need to leave few text box blank, but due to the code I am not able to submit the form with optional text box.
Kindly refer the jquery code which is used for validating ALL text box

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
        var isValid = true;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                isValid = false;
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "1px solid red",
                    "background": "#FFCECE"
                });
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "",
                    "background": ""
                });
            }
        });
        if (isValid == false) 
            e.preventDefault();
        else 
            alert('Thank you for submitting');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class on text boxes which are mandatory:

```
<input type="text" value="1" class="mandatory"/>
<input type="text" value="2"/>
```

and then:

```
 $('input[type="text"].mandatory').each(function() {


 });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5PcDb/)

Answer (score 0):

Your input selector is too general. One way to go from here is to add a class to all the inputs you want to validate. E.g.:

```
<input type="text" class="validate">
<input type="text">
<input type="text" class="validate">
```

Then, all you need to do, is change the selector in your validation function

from this:

```
$('input[type="text"]')
```

to this:

```
$('input.validate')
```

That way the only inputs to be validated are the ones with `class="validate"`. The middle one won't be validated.